Dictionary inside configuration section is always null or empty
I am trying to get some options from the appsettings like this:
{
    "Currency": {
        "DefaultCode": "EUR",
        "Url":"some url",
        "Providers": {
            "DefaultCode": "EUR",
            "Url":"some url"
        }
    }
}

I have these classes for these type of options:
public class CurrencyConfiguration
{
    public string DefaultCode { get; set;}
    public string Url { get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string, CurrencyProvider> Providers { get; set;}
}

public class CurrencyProvider
{
    public string DefaultCode { get; set;}
    public string Url { get; set;}
}

But when I try like this:
var configs = Configuration.GetSection("Currency").Get<CurrencyConfiguration>();

I get null for CurrencyProviders. The other fields are filled correctly.

The Providers in the json is not a Dictionary<string, CurrencyProvider>. It is just an object. Change the CurrencyConfiguration class to this.
public class CurrencyConfiguration
{
    public string DefaultCode { get; set;}
    public string Url { get; set;}
    public CurrencyProvider Providers { get; set;}
}

That will deserialize the current json properly. If for some other reason the CurrencyConfiguration class needs to be a dictionary, then change the class to this.
public class CurrencyConfiguration
{
    public string DefaultCode { get; set;}
    public string Url { get; set;}
    public Dictionary<string, string> Providers { get; set;}
}

But this will simply be a dictionary as the key value pair being strings.

Technically the json is a dictionary, it is just a Dictionary<string, string> and not Dictionary<string, CurrencyProvider>.

But is there another way of making it Dictionary<string, CurrencyProvider> I don't want to make the key values as strings, I want to add more properties with different types there, for example:
"Providers": {             "DefaultCode": "EUR",             "Url":"some url"             "IsEnabled": true         },         "OtherProvider": {             "DefaultCode": "EUR",             "Url":"some url",             "IsEnabled": false         },

Wrap the json like this
"Currency":[{"DefaultCode": "eur"},{"Url":"Some url"}]
Basically just wrap each dictionary item in a {} with a [] surrounding the entirety of the dictionary.

But a dictionary requireds a unique key for every item and if there is a several items, it will fail as the key default code will be used multiple times.
